# use regular expressions and categorize

Tags: regex, oracle, substr

I want to use regular expressions and then what ever the result comes out, I want to place it into colums.
For example:
I have these results coming from regular expressions say,

```
hp
dell
intel
lenovo
```

Assume above are the column names in the table.
Now I want to turn the query say, if hp then I need to mark as 'Y' in hp column
similarly, If the output is dell I want to mark as 'Y' in dell column
If the output is intel I want to mark as 'Y' in intel column
If the output is lenovo I want to mark as 'Y' in lenovo column

something like this

```
dell hp intel lenovo
Y    Y    Y      Y
```

Comment: Clear as mud. If your question is how to make Y appear in the right column (for example, if hp then Y in the "hp column"), why do you care HOW the value hp came about? Why do you care it was the output from a regular expression and not from something else? Please pretend you don't know what the question is, and read your sentences above (and you have no other information). Does this make sense to you? If it does, you are much above our level. If it doesn't make sense to you, how can it make sense to us?

Comment: What does the data you're working with look like? We need examples in order to make reasonable recommendations. Please edit your question and include examples of the data you're working with, and what the results should be.

Comment: To both of your questions. Our front end is java application. We support i.e. we give list of stored procedures for them to insert/update/delete data and other operations. Coming to the question that i asked. The input will be in comma separated*. If that is the case, how do i insert the data into corresponding columns. Please let me know if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot` function like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT 'hp' NAME  
  FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'dell'   
  FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'intel' 
  FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'lenovo' 
  FROM DUAL
)
PIVOT
(
  MAX('Y')
  FOR NAME IN ('hp' AS hp, 'dell' AS dell, 'intel' AS intel ,'lenovo' AS lenovo)
)
```